# Oracle SQL iterate through dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains user system login information.

I would like to report on any "out of hours" activity - times are identified as being between 20:00 and 06:00 the following day.

I can run a simple query which returns the information I need:

```
select to_char(logon_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') , 
username from sessions 
where to_char(logon_time, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI') 
between '&YEAR-&MONTH-01 20:00' and '&YEAR-&MONTH-02 06:00';
```

Note that I have to manually define individual 'days' in this query - in this case, it's from 20:00 on the 01st to 06:00 on the 02nd day of the month.

What I'd like to do is run a report for a large date range (for example, the beginning of the year right up to SYSDATE), automatically iterating over the individual days while accounting for the fact that the subquery already has a specfic between date range clause which spans multiple days.

I can't get my head round how to achieve this.  Any clues greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you could show us some sample data it would be nice.  A picture is worth a thousand words for SQL questions.

Comment: You can compare the time portion and date portions as separate conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify all out-of-hours logons using:

```
SELECT logon_time,
       username
FROM   sessions
WHERE  EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST( logon_time AS TIMESTAMP ) ) < 6
OR     EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST( logon_time AS TIMESTAMP ) ) >= 20
```

If you want it for a particular date range then:

```
SELECT logon_time,
       username
FROM   sessions
WHERE  (   EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST( logon_time AS TIMESTAMP ) ) < 6
       OR  EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST( logon_time AS TIMESTAMP ) ) >= 20 )
AND    logon_time BETWEEN DATE '2016-05-01' AND SYSDATE
```

Will get the out-of-hours logons from midnight 1st May to the current time.